# Speed up SPI transfer

Tags: python, pi-2, spi

So I need to transfer a byte on the spi interface on raspberry pi. Here's my code in python

```py
import spidev
import time
import binimp

fhandle=open("white.txt")

initial=binimp.extract(fhandle,'192','28')
final=binimp.metdat(initial,'192','28')

spi = spidev.SpiDev() #create spi object
spi.open(0, 1) #open spi port 0, device (CS) 1
spi.max_speed_hz = 976000

try:
 while True:
     for i in final:
         resp = spi.xfer2([ord(i)])
except KeyboardInterrupt: # Ctrl+C pressed, so…
    spi.close() # … close the port before exit
```

Basically I'm just sending a byte one by one to the SPI (ignore the `newbinimp` functions, they're basically generating a sequence of characters). The issue is that there is a lot of time in between each consecutive byte transfer as shown in the image[image: SPI on logic analayzer]. I'm using a logic analyzer to see the bytes being transferred. As you can see there is a 61.4 micro second wait before each byte is transferred. Is there any way to reduce this time? Thank you so much[image: **Python code made easier to read**]

Comment: I thought you could send a long list of bytes by the spidev command writebytes2(list of values) - https://pypi.org/project/spidev/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you send multiple bytes in one transfer?

If you have to send byte by byte I suggest you use C instead of Python.